# Bloomfilter with AWS Services

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, bloom-filter

I would like to give my users the ability to swip elements like Tinder.

Since I don't want these elements to show up over and over again, I would put them into a table/list and then check if they are already there.

It was recommended to solve this with a Bloomfilter.

Now, how do I solve this best with an AWS service?
I use AWS AppSync and DynamoDB

I could imagine that the user simply gets an item in a table:

```
{owner: "232-4232-323", seenCards: "bloomFilterHashes"}
```

Then I would be able to create the filter from the data again and again?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about dynamo, but you can use [redis](https://redislabs.com/redis-best-practices/bloom-filter-pattern/) service from aws to archive this.